# What does while(i) do?

Tags: while-loop

I know that while(1) is an infinite loop but what exactly does while(i) mean?

```
int i=5;
...
while(i)
{
i=i-1;
printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

In the end, the number "0" will be printed. What I do not understand is why is this not an infinite loop and why does it stop at 0?

Answer (score 6):

It stops because `0` evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Zero means False and any non-zero (even floats) value means True.

Consider this:

```
float i=5.5;
...
while(i)
{
  i=i-1.5;
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

This also works even though it is not an integer.
So, while(i) just means while(i!=0)

Answer (score 0):

It implicitly means `while (i!=0)`. So basicly your code is equivalent to

```
int i=5;
...
while(i!=0)
{
i=i-1;
printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

which explains its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

All non-zero integers are interpreted as `true`, and `0` is interpreted as `false`. If this in C (and not C++), then in fact there aren't actually built-in boolean literals `true`, and `false`. A false value in C is represented by the integer zero, and a true value by a non-zero integer.